# Problem with Pytube

Tags: python

I'm new to linux and I tried to use Pytube. I installed it correctly, no errors, everything works fine. But when I run the program nothing outputs, nothing downloads. Here is the code I use.

```
 from pytube import YouTube
 yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3D7Y_ycSms')
 yt.title
 print(yt.title)
```

Comment: How do you run your script? I've tested it and it only print the title as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you could use youtube-dl to download videos.  youtube-dl is a command-line program to download videos from YouTube.com and a few more sites.

To install :

```
$ sudo apt install youtube-dl
```

To download your video write in the terminal :

```
$ youtube-dl 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3D7Y_ycSms'
```

To only get the title :

```
$ youtube-dl -e 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3D7Y_ycSms'
```

For the manual :

```
$ man youtube-dl
```

Comment: Well, if I'm correct this is  youtube_dl library, but I'm trying to use Pytube